# Copy full row from a table's database

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm using VB.Net and I have a database contains two tables "Personne" and "PersonneCopy" ( Same schema as Personne [4 columns = N°, FirstName, LastName, B_Day])

I load the first table in a Datagridview all it's fine with that, here's the code:

```
Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= .\BD.mdb")
Dim SqlRequete As String = "Select * From Personne"
Dim Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlRequete, Connection)
Dim DataSet As New DataSet
Adapter.Fill(DataSet, "Tb1")
Dim DataTable As New DataTable
DataTable = DataSet.Tables("Tb1")
DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable
```

Is there any way to add the full row that was selected from DataGridView1 to the table "PersonneCopy"?

And by the way I tried this code with an other Datagridview to get the index of the row selected and it works.

```
Dim Index As Integer = DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value
Dim SqlRequete As String = "Select * From Personne where N°=" & Index.ToString
Dim Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlRequete, Connection)
Dim Ds As New DataSet
Adapter.Fill(Ds, "Tb")
DataGridView2.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Dim drCopy as DataRow
Dim tbCopy as Datatable 

tbCopy = .... 'PersonneCopy table

drCopy=tbCopy.NewRow()
For i as integer=0 to drCopy.columns.count-1
  drCopy(i)=Ds.Tables(0).rows(0).items(i)   '---------> or you can change rows(0)
Next
tbCopy.Rows.Add(drCopy)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
But the drCopy as Datarow has no columns member.
And dstRow means drCopy here ?

Comment: Ups .. sorry ! It has to be 'drCopy' .. and drCopy will have same structure with tbCopy if you fill the tbCopy = .........